# how to store primary key in session with stored procedure

Tags: asp.net

I have login page for which I have used stored procedure. I am using session to store id of user which is primary key. When I enter wrong username and password it should redirect to some other page but it is giving me exception as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." My code for login.aspx.cs is:

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select artistId from artist where Username=@username and Artistpass=@password",con);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusr.Text);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpass.Text);
        con.Close();
         Session["username"] = txtusr.Text;
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@username", txtusr.Text.Trim());
        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@password", txtpass.Text.Trim());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("login", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            Response.Redirect("afterlogin.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Unsuccessful");

        }
        con.Close();
        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        int id = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
        Session["ID"] = id;
        con.Close();
```

plz help.

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: Bzz `MessageBox.Show` in ASP.net ?

Comment: ?cmd1.ExecuteScalar - where is cmd1 declared?

Comment: I am getting error at int id = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: Shouldn't it be (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();?

Comment: @AlexK. That is very funny.

Comment: You don't even need to write all this stuff take a look at Asp.net Identity http://www.asp.net/identity Unless you really know what you are doing you are probably making more work and more security loopholes than you need to.  That snippet suggests you are storing passwords in plain text, which is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns null if your where statement doesn't find a match for your user and password

So you cannot cast a null return value to an integer

```
    object id = cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
    Session["ID"] = id;
    con.Close();
```

this, of course, means that you need to check the Session["ID"] variable in the redirected page to see it it is null